# Convert integer years or months into days in SQL impala

Tags: sql, impala

I have two columns; both have integer values. One Representing years, and the other representing months.
My goal is to perform calculations in days (integer), so I have to convert both to calendar days,  to achieve that, taking in consideration that we have years with both 365 and 366 days.

Example in pseudo code:

```
Select Convert(years_int) to days, Convert(months int) to days
from table.


Real Example:
if --> Years = 1 and Months = 12
1) Convert both to days to compare them: Years = 365 days; Months = 365 days

After conversion : (Years = Months) Returns TRUE.
```

The problem is when we have years = 10 (for example), we must take in account the fact that at least two of them have 366 days. The same with Months - we have 30 and 31 days. So I need to compensate that fact to get the most accurate possible value in days.

Thanks in advance

Comment: The syntax of what you want to do is tightly related to the DBMS you're using, as every DBMS has their own functions. Update your post with one DBMS tag.

Comment: Did you check: [impala date and time functions](https://impala.apache.org/docs/build/html/topics/impala_datetime_functions.html) ??   (TO_TIMESTAMP looks pretty usable....)

Comment: You can not do it. year is like 2022,2023 etc. and month will be like 1,2,3... how can you get 2nd day of Feb of 2022 using month and year? You need a date parameter.

Comment: @Koushik Roy I've edited this post. Can you only help me on how to perform the mathematical calculations?

Comment: i can provide some calculation. can you pls give some sample - input data and expected output

Comment: Sure @koushik Roy. Years = 50; Months = 530. Can you convert both to days to compare them or perform calculations?
I've read someware that 1 month = 30.436875 days and 1 year = 365.2425 days.

Comment: i think then you can use either of them. But your sample doesnt make sense, 530 months is nearly 44 years and 2months which is less than 50years. 50 years is 600months.

Comment: @Koushik Roy, the goal is only convert years or months to days in a most accurate possible way. Theres no kind of relation between them.

Comment: @LEOPOLDO: A month is not 30.436... days. Maybe on **average** it is, but in real life it's just 28,29,30 or 31 days where 30 and 31 are most common, and 28 or 29 only are used for the second month in a year.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From integers to timestamp can be done in PostgreSQL. I do not have impala, but hopefully below script will help you getting this done using impala:

```sql
with 
 year as (select 2022 as y union select 2023),
 month as (select generate_series(1,12) as m),
 day as(select generate_series(1,31) as d )
select y,m,d,dt from (
   select 
      y,m,d,
      to_date(ds,'YYYYMMDD')+(((d-1)::char(2))||' day')::interval dt
   from (  select 
              *, 
              y::char(4)|| right('0'||m::char(2),2) || right('0'||0::char(2),2) as ds 
           from year,month,day
        ) x
) y
where extract(year from dt)=y and extract(month from dt)=m
order by dt
;
```

see: [DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/PdzyNQzX)

Used functions in this query and, a way, to convert them to `imapala` (remember I do not use that tool/language/dialect)

| function | impala alternative |
| --- | --- |
| to_date(a,b) | This will convert the string `a` to a date using the format `b`. Using impala you can use [CAST(expression AS type FORMAT pattern)](https://impala.apache.org/docs/build/html/topics/impala_conversion_functions.html#:%7E:text=CAST(expression%20AS%20type%20FORMAT%20pattern)) |
| y::char(4) | Cast y to a char(4), Using imala you can use: [CAST(expression AS type)](https://impala.apache.org/docs/build/html/topics/impala_conversion_functions.html#:%7E:text=CAST(expression%20AS%20type)) |
| right(a,b) | Use: [right()](https://impala.apache.org/docs/build/html/topics/impala_string_functions.html#string_functions__right) |
| `\\` | Use: [concat()](https://impala.apache.org/docs/build/html/topics/impala_string_functions.html#string_functions__concat) |
| generate_series(a,b) | This generates a serie of numbers from a to (an inclusing) b. A SQL altervative is to write `SELECT 1 as x union SELECT 2 union SELECT 3`, which generates the same series as `generate_series(1,3)` in PostgreSQL |
| extract(year from a) | Get the year from the datetime field `a`, see [YEAR()](https://impala.apache.org/docs/build/html/topics/impala_datetime_functions.html#datetime_functions__year:%7E:text=YEAR(TIMESTAMP%20/%20DATE%20date)) |

One *special* case is this one `to_date(ds,'YYYYMMDD')+(((d-1)::char(2))||' day')::interval`

- This will convert `ds` (with datatype CHAR(8)) to a date, and then add (using `+`) a number of days (like: `'4 day'`)
- Because I included all days until 31, this will fail in Februari, April, June, September, November because those months do not have 31 days.  This is corrected by the WHERE clause in the end (`where extract(year from dt)=y and extract(month from dt)=m`)

Comment: Not sure if this answers the question. 1. OP has only month and year and not a day field. 2. Impala doesnt have generate series...

Comment: Hi @Luuk. Thank you in advance. Like Koushik Roy said, this solution doesn't work in impala. Can you show me please in a mathematical point of view, how perform the calcs, so I can develop the solution in Impala?

Comment: OK, i will added some conversion steps (and hopefully be complete in doing so.....)

Comment: Done adding the explanation, which should help to convert above to impala.

Comment: @KoushikRoy: I use the fixed number 1 to 31, because I also do not know how many days   a month does have, but the where clause at the end corrects that part....